# Reverse proxy with Apache and static content behind application inside of jetty

Tags: spring, apache, proxy, jetty

My applications is spring based and served by jetty. The current setup looks like this.

Apache - > Reverse proxy -> Embedded Jetty -> Application

When I access the app directly (*http://127.0.0.1:15000*) without reverse proxy the static resources are loaded (css, .js etc) but if I access it through reverse proxy 
(*https://127.0.0.1/app/*) it doesn't work.

Here are my configs.

**apache2.conf**

```
ProxyPass /app/ http://127.0.0.1:15000/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://127.0.0.1:15000/
SSLProxyEngine on 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /app$ /app/ [R]
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
 ...
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 ...
```

I would like that in both ways the static content will be delivered.

Comment: The easiest solution is to make the paths match, i.e. use /app as the servlet context path.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late. But for anyone who might end up here, Adding a mapping to your resources path will solve the problem.

```
ProxyPass /app/resources http://127.0.0.1:15000/app/resources
ProxyPassReverse /app/resources http://127.0.0.1:15000/app/resources
```

This should be added before your existing mapping.(longest URL comes first, as whichever mapping is read first, wins)